# Laptop does not actually turn off on shutdown

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown

I have a laptop with lubuntu 13.04

When given the shut down command, it exits the graphical interface, shows the lubuntu logo and then the screen goes black, but the computer never actually goes off until I press and hold the power button.

Is it possible to fix?

Comment: Do you use a button in GUI for that or perhaps something like `sudo shutdown now` in the terminal?

Comment: Try using `init 0`. what is the result for it.

Comment: @Tarun that worked! Any ideas why the usual method is not functioning?

Comment: @moon.musick I've used both, they have the same effect as described in OP.

Comment: init is an initialisation script, `init 0` can also be used to shutdown systems or `shutdown` command can also be used. Here's a link http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shutdown-ubuntu-linux-computer/  Try the different types of commands listed and notice if there is anykind of unusual behavior still by your system.

Comment: How about `shutdown -h` or `shutdown -P` (for `halt` or `poweroff`, respectively)? `shutdown` by itself doesn't work on any of my machines running Ubuntu or Mint, while when run with `-h` didn't work only for some older Supermicro server boards with long-outdated BIOS (a BIOS update helped).

Comment: @moon.musick both of those did indeed power off the computer!

Comment: @user11177 Most often it does work. Anyways, I can't help you with the GUI - I have no machine running Lubuntu, but it is likely it calls `shutdown` instead of `shutdown -h` - the behavior is consistent with the commands. As a workaround, you may try to bind the power button to a specified action - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Boot_Install_Login#I_want_to_bind_the_power-button_to_change_computer_state.2C_how_do_I_do_it.3F If you are happy enough with the terminal option, you may accept Tarun's answer, or I may post mine.

Comment: @moon.musick Taruns answer, while informative, didn't address the problem directly (in the manner his comment did) so for the sake of clarity I'm waiting for you or someone else to post an answer which includes one of the methods you guys have provided. Thank you both by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `shutdown -h` or `shutdown -P`, for `halt` or `poweroff`. It should turn off the machine completely. Apparently the `-P` option is safer (meaning it is more likely to cause the poweroff in different Linux distros), as it is more explicit and much less dependent on the implementation.

From the man page of `shutdown`:

```
-h     Requests that the system be either halted or powered off after it has been brought down, with the choice as to which left up to the system.
-P     Requests that the system be powered off after it has been brought down.
```

Comment: This is marked as answer, which part answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more useful link as it says using only `shutdown` doesn't turns off the system you need to add extra parameters to it as well.

[Shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73696/what-is-the-proper-terminal-way-to-shutdown)