# What is the "friendliest" shutdown CLI command to use with KDE Connect?

Tags: command-line, shutdown, kde-connect

I want to shutdown computer with my phone using KDE Connect. That can be easily done by adding a shutdown command in the setting of the Runcommand plugin within the KDE Connect program in Linux.

[image]

The idea is to close the applications gracefully without abruptly killing them and losing last configurations, for example.

I know about `systemctl poweroff`.

I read under [this question](https://serverfault.com/a/327766/256174) that "`shutdown -h now` or `shutdown -r now` are graceful", and also that scripts involved may vary depending on the distribution. What is the situation in Ubuntu?

Are the commands above preferable to `systemctl poweroff` for my purpose?

Comment: Related (but perhaps outdated): [What is the proper terminal-way to shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73696/what-is-the-proper-terminal-way-to-shutdown)

Comment: @Melebius - the title is similar but that question is not mentioning the "graceful" or  "friendly"  aspect. Anyway, I will edit my title to make it KDE-Connect-specific (I don't want sudo etc).

Comment: I *suppose* (but don’t know) every single one of the different shutdown commands kills the processes equally gracefully by sending `SIGTERM` – that’s `kill`’s default signal and widely considered to be *The Right Thing™* to do. Most importantly, every reasonable software saves its data and only then exits when receiving this signal.

Comment: Oh, run `file $(which shutdown)` to see what `shutdown` in fact is. ;) Well, I suppose  there’s not really a difference…

Comment: `qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 2 0` is what you want. This is from https://superuser.com/a/396091/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A graceful shutdown means that the programs receive a hang up signal (HUP). If the program is developed properly, it will listen to this signal and act accordingly (prepare the program to get shut down, clearing used memory, deleting tmp files, etc.).

It does not really matter, if it is done on the GUI or on the terminal, the HUP signal will be send either way.

This also answers your question if Ubuntu behaves differently then other distros. It does not. The mechanism is the same. An odd behaviour can be expected from programs which don't act properly when they get a HUP signal, but this is because the program does not do it properly, it has nothing to do with the distro.

P.S.:

```
shutdown -h
```

will power off the system, while

```
shutdown -r
```

will reboot the system (so this is unusable for you)

Just use `shutdown` or add `-P` or `--poweroff` (but this is the default anyway according to the man page).

Comment: P.S.S.: this is totally different to reboot, which sends the KILL signal instead of HUP, hence the system just kills everything and reboots the system. Tr5y for yourself and do a time measurement of reboot and shutdown -r 0

Comment: could you add a few info on why `systemctl poweroff` is also used/usable?  is `systemctl` adding  something to the procedure?

Comment: see systemctl as a "wrapper". systemctl is a command line tool from systemd and systemd is (not only but also) responsible for starting and stopping service. But in the end, systemd also sends a HUP signal.

Comment: According to `man shutdown`, `shutdown -h` is “[e]quivalent to --poweroff, unless --halt is specified”, while `shutdown -H` halts the machine!

Comment: @dessert - indeed. but is "halt the machine" (`-H`, `--halt`) action *graceful*?

Comment: @s1mmel - considering the man page: I see no `-p` argument, it's `-P`, `--poweroff` or `-h`. While "halt" is `-H`, not `-h`, as per dessert's comment.

Comment: @ciprius - shutdown is always graceful no matter if the machine is shutdown or halted.

Comment: BTW I changed -p to -P and HALT to power off. Thanks for the input.